# Jenkins get URL of Downstream Job without Waiting

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-groovy

How do I retrieve the URL of a Jenkins downstream job without waiting for the job to finish? I can access the downstream job in the Jenkins web interface, but I cannot retrieve the URL immediately in the upstream pipeline.

```
my_job = null

my_job = build job: 'Downstream Job', wait: false, propagate: false

my_job_url = my_job.getAbsoluteUrl() // my_job is still null
```

Is this not possible?

Comment: Try adding a 5 second sleep.

Comment: I added a `waitUntil` block in Jenkins for `my_job` to not be null. However, `my_job` comes out as not null only after the job finishes. I wonder if there is an alternative approach to immediately retrieve the job url or job number.

Comment: Seems that this is actually not possible, but I found kind of a workaround for some usecases here: [JENKINS-31392](https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-31392).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given what @roman said in the comment, [JENKINS-31392](https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-31392) is the best workaround.

Answer (score 2):

When you use the build step with wait: false, it returns a Queue.Item object representing the item in the build queue. Since the downstream job has not yet started, there is no URL for it to provide at that point. Therefore, you cannot immediately retrieve the URL of a downstream job when using wait: false with the build step.

One possible workaround for this is to use the Jenkins REST API to retrieve the URL of the downstream job. You can use the Jenkins.getJob() method to get an instance of the downstream job and then call getAbsoluteUrl() on that instance to retrieve its URL.

Here is an example of how you can retrieve the URL of a downstream job using the Jenkins REST API:

```
import jenkins.model.*
import hudson.model.*

def jobName = 'Downstream Job'
def jenkins = Jenkins.getInstance()
def job = jenkins.getItemByFullName(jobName, Job.class)

def jobUrl = job.getAbsoluteUrl()

println "Downstream job URL: ${jobUrl}"
```

This code will retrieve the instance of the downstream job and print its URL to the console. You can modify it to suit your needs and integrate it into your upstream pipeline script.

Answer (score 1):

There is a new release of [Pipeline: Build Step plugin](https://plugins.jenkins.io/pipeline-build-step/) with following change:

- Implement option to wait only until the downstream build is started

> Add a new option **waitForStart** to the build step. The waitForStart
> option changes the behavior of the build step to block until the
> downstream build is started and a valid RunWrapper can be returned.

See also [JENKINS-60849](https://issues.jenkins.io/browse/JENKINS-60849)

This makes it possible to optain the downstream build (and link) as soon as it's build starts.